# explanation about du command linux diskusage

Tags: linux, du

What is the difference between these two:

```
du -h --max-depth=2 /usr/* | sort -nr | head -n 20
```

And:

```
du -h --max-depth=2 /usr/ | sort -nr | head -n 20
```

I would like to display the 20 biggest folder under /usr folder.
Does this 20 folder includes the overall subfolders sizes as well ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some important changes in the behavior of these two invocations. Let's use an example, with the structure created by:

```
mkdir mydir/{.a1,a2,a3}/{.b1,b2}/{.c1,c2} -p
```

If you invoke `du --max-depth=2 mydir` you will get:

```
0       mydir/.a1/.b1
0       mydir/.a1/b2
0       mydir/.a1
0       mydir/a2/.b1
0       mydir/a2/b2
0       mydir/a2
0       mydir/a3/.b1
0       mydir/a3/b2
0       mydir/a3
0       mydir/
```

But if you run:

```
du --max-depth=2 mydir/*`
```

the wildcard character will be expanded and it will become an equivalent of:

```
du --max-depth=2 mydir/a2 mydir/a3
```

which will give you the following result:

```
0       mydir/a2/.b1/.c1
0       mydir/a2/.b1/c2
0       mydir/a2/.b1
0       mydir/a2/b2/.c1
0       mydir/a2/b2/c2
0       mydir/a2/b2
0       mydir/a2
0       mydir/a3/.b1/.c1
0       mydir/a3/.b1/c2
0       mydir/a3/.b1
0       mydir/a3/b2/.c1
0       mydir/a3/b2/c2
0       mydir/a3/b2
0       mydir/a3
```

The important thing to note here is that it will omit the `.a1` directory. In order to include it you would have to run something similar to: `du --max-depth=2 mydir/{.[!.]*,*}` (but I guess there might be an easier and more generic way that I don't know of). It will also not calculate the overall size of the `mydir` directory.

And yes, the sizes reported by `du` include sizes of the subfolders.

Answer (score 3):

The former counts visible objects within `/usr`. The latter counts all objects under `/usr`, including `/usr` itself.